# Firefox 27 : NSS_Init fails

Tags: firefox, nss

I am working on password recovery tool with nss3.dll. I have loaded nss3.dll but NSS_Init function fails. here is my code.

```
typedef enum _SECStatus {
    SECWouldBlock = -2,
    SECFailure = -1,
    SECSuccess = 0
} SECStatus;
typedef struct SECItemStr SECItem;
typedef struct PLArenaPool      PLArenaPool;
typedef SECStatus      (*NSS_Init) (const char *configdir);
void init()
{
   HINSTANCE LoadMe ;
   LoadMe = LoadLibrary(L"nss3.dll"); //Library gets loaded successfully.

   NSS_Init                NSSInit1;
   NSSInit1               = (NSS_Init) GetProcAddress(LoadMe, "NSS_Init");

   const char * path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\0rhq2lpu.default";

  SECStatus result = (*NSSInit1) (path);
  if( result != SECSuccess )
  {
  // fails here..  
    return ;
  }

 //Here will code of password decryption...
}
```

Always i get SECFailure on calling NSS_Init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code NSS_Init method is not working because i am not loading nss3.dll from path `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\nss3.dll`
I am copying the nss3.dll to my solution folder and loading it. As nss3.dll requires other supporting dll to work.

Here is my working code.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<atlenc.h>


typedef enum {
    siBuffer = 0,
    siClearDataBuffer = 1,
    siCipherDataBuffer = 2,
    siDERCertBuffer = 3,
    siEncodedCertBuffer = 4,
    siDERNameBuffer = 5,
    siEncodedNameBuffer = 6,
    siAsciiNameString = 7,
    siAsciiString = 8,
    siDEROID = 9,
    siUnsignedInteger = 10,
    siUTCTime = 11,
    siGeneralizedTime = 12,
    siVisibleString = 13,
    siUTF8String = 14,
    siBMPString = 15
} SECItemType;

typedef struct SECItemStr SECItem;

struct SECItemStr {
    SECItemType type;
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned int len;
};

typedef enum _SECStatus {
    SECWouldBlock = -2,
    SECFailure = -1,
    SECSuccess = 0
} SECStatus;

typedef int PRBool;
typedef unsigned int PRUint32;
/* /security/nss/lib/pk11wrap/secmodti.h */
/* /security/nss/lib/softoken/secmodt.h*/
/* typedef struct PK11SlotInfoStr PK11SlotInfo; */
typedef void PK11SlotInfo;      /* self defined */

/* /security/nss/lib/nss/nss.h */
typedef SECStatus (__cdecl *NSS_InitFunc)(const char *configdir);
typedef SECStatus (__cdecl *NSS_ShutdownFunc)(void);
/* /security/nss/lib/pk11wrap/pk11pub.h */
typedef PK11SlotInfo *(__cdecl *PK11_GetInternalKeySlotFunc)(void);
typedef void (__cdecl *PK11_FreeSlotFunc)(PK11SlotInfo *slot);
typedef SECStatus (__cdecl *PK11_AuthenticateFunc)(PK11SlotInfo *slot, PRBool loadCerts, void *wincx);
/* /security/nss/lib/pk11wrap/pk11sdr.h */
typedef SECStatus (__cdecl *PK11SDR_DecryptFunc)(SECItem *data, SECItem *result, void *cx);
/* /security/nss/lib/pk11wrap/pk11pub.h */
typedef SECStatus (__cdecl *PK11_CheckUserPasswordFunc)(PK11SlotInfo *slot, const char *pw);
/* /security/nss/lib/util/secitem.h */
typedef void (__cdecl *SECITEM_ZfreeItemFunc)(SECItem *zap, PRBool freeit);

typedef void (*SECITEM_AllocItem)(SECItem & item, int len);


void decryptFirefoxPassword(char *dest,const char *encoded_cred)
{
    // Check to see if the library was loaded successfully 
    HINSTANCE nss3_handle;
    HINSTANCE glueLib;

    glueLib = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\mozglue.dll");
    nss3_handle = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\nss3.dll");
    // Check to see if the library was loaded successfully 
    if(glueLib && nss3_handle)
    {
        SECStatus init_status;
        if ((NSS_Init = (NSS_InitFunc)
            GetProcAddress(nss3_handle, "NSS_Init")) &&
            (NSS_Shutdown = (NSS_ShutdownFunc)
            GetProcAddress(nss3_handle, "NSS_Shutdown")) &&
            (PK11_GetInternalKeySlot = (PK11_GetInternalKeySlotFunc)
            GetProcAddress(nss3_handle, "PK11_GetInternalKeySlot")) &&
            (PK11_FreeSlot = (PK11_FreeSlotFunc)
            GetProcAddress(nss3_handle, "PK11_FreeSlot")) &&
            (PK11_Authenticate = (PK11_AuthenticateFunc)
            GetProcAddress(nss3_handle, "PK11_Authenticate")) &&
            (PK11SDR_Decrypt = (PK11SDR_DecryptFunc)
            GetProcAddress(nss3_handle, "PK11SDR_Decrypt")) &&
            (PK11_CheckUserPassword = (PK11_CheckUserPasswordFunc)
            GetProcAddress(nss3_handle, "PK11_CheckUserPassword")) &&
            (SECITEM_ZfreeItem = (SECITEM_ZfreeItemFunc)
            GetProcAddress(nss3_handle, "SECITEM_ZfreeItem")))
        {
            init_status = NSS_Init(m_strDefaultProfilePath.toStdString().c_str());

            if(init_status == SECSuccess)
            {
                size_t cred_len;
                int pnDestLen=MAX_CRED_LENGTH;
                unsigned char decoded_cred[MAX_CRED_LENGTH];

                PK11SlotInfo *slot;


                cred_len = strlen(encoded_cred);
                if (! Base64Decode(encoded_cred,cred_len,decoded_cred,&pnDestLen))
                    return;

                if (!(slot = PK11_GetInternalKeySlot()))
                    return;
                if (PK11_Authenticate(slot, TRUE, NULL) == SECSuccess)
                {
                    SECItem data, result;
                    result.data = NULL;
                    result.len = 0;
                    data.data = decoded_cred;
                    data.len = decoded_size(encoded_cred);

                    if (PK11SDR_Decrypt(&data, &result, NULL) == SECSuccess) 
                    {
                        strncpy_s(dest, MAX_CRED_LENGTH, (char *)result.data, result.len);
                        SECITEM_ZfreeItem(&result, FALSE);
                    }
                }
                PK11_FreeSlot(slot);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but since i had the same issue keep in mind that except from what OP's issue was, you should bear in mind that you may encounter the same issue because:

1) You may need admin rights to load the dll's.

2) Your program needs to have the same bits as the dll. If for example your program is 32 bit and the nss3.dll from firefox is 64 bit, the library loading will fail.

I hope that this will save time from feature readers.

Comment: Thus a case of using "raw" decryption is still actual